# How cause association callback in rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, associations

How to track in the models this command

```
=> order = Order.create
=> order.items << Item.first // this command
```

if i have such models:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :order_items
   has_many :items, through: :order_items
end
class Item < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :order_items
   has_many :orders, through: :order_items
end
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :order
   belongs_to :item
end
```

I try use after_add for example, but I did not succeed.
 For example my task: 
   In controller`s (OrderController) method create:

```
def create
 @order = Order.create(order_params)
 @order.items << Item.find(params[:id])
end
```

And i have that models Order or Item track this (when i add item to order) and print me message in console (for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the Rails Guides about [Association Callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/association_basics.html#association-callbacks). There is, for example, an `after_add` callback.

```
# in your Order model
has_many :items, after_add: :track_item_added

private

def track_item_added(item)
  # your tracking code, for example
  Rails.logger.debug("Item ##{item.id} added to order ##{id}")
end
```